How to render my web component before connectedCallback but after constructor?
I am making a custom web component using vanilla JavaScript and am having some issues with when the component should be rendered.
At first I had my render() and hydrate() calls inside the constructor of the component. This worked well when the component was already part of the DOM to begin with, however, if the component was created using document.createElement("my-button"), then the render() call would end up executing before I would have the chance to add attributes and child elements ect. which was a major problem.
The other alternative, which is what my code below shows, is it have the render() and hydrate() calls inside the connectedCallback() method. This fixes the document.createElement("my-button") problem, however, it introduces a new one. Because the connectedCallback() only executes after the element is added to the DOM, I could potentially get a FOUC (Flash of unstyled content) before the component is finished rendering. It would've been nice if there was a beforeConnectedCallback() so I can execute the code before it is added to the DOM, but this does not seem to exist.
So what should I do to get my component to automatically render and hydrate before it is added to the DOM?
Here is my component:
class MYButton extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.render();
        this.hydrate();
    }

    render() {
        let type = this.getAttribute("type");
        if (type === "link") {
            this.elmButton = document.createElement("a");
            this.elmButton.setAttribute("href", this.getAttribute("href"));
        } else {
            this.elmButton = document.createElement("button");
            this.elmButton.setAttribute("type", type);
        }
        while (this.firstChild) {
            this.elmButton.appendChild(this.firstChild);
        }
        this.appendChild(this.elmButton);
    }

    hydrate() {
        this.elmButton.addEventListener("click", () => alert("hello world"));
    }
}

customElements.define('my-button', MYButton);


"I could potentially get a FOUC (Flash of unstyled content) before the component is finished rendering" - no, you can't. Unless your rendering does something asynchronous.

"the render() call would end up executing before I would have the chance to add attributes and child elements etc. which was a major problem." - instead of delaying the rendering, you should be handling attribute changes regardless whether they occur before or after mounting the component

@OscarR ... I'm with Bergi the attribute changed lifecycle callback in combination with the connectedCallback gives one everything one does need to know. Since your component features a sole type attribute you can build upon this approach.

+1 for your constructor conclusion, you can't add DOM there
8 out of 10 developers get this wrong... because they define their components with async or type=module after all DOM is parsed
-1 for your connectedCallback conclusion, it does NOT fire after DOM is created.

The connectedCallback fires on the opening tag <my-button>
lightDOM is not parsed yet.

For long read see my blogpost:
Web Component developers do not connect with the connectedCallback (yet)
The challenge with your Web Component is, you both want to create new lightDOM (your button code) AND read existing lightDOM (your firstChild)
Your create after read is perfectly fine, otherwise you would be endlessy adding that new button.
But there will always be a FOUC/Layout Shift, since you can't have the cake and eat it...

if you want that (unstyled) lightDOM you will have to wait for it.

But you can have the Web Component be hidden and display it when all work is done,
or add a fancy opacity transition yourself.
Without the render and hydrate mumbo-jumbo, the Web Component is:


const createElement = 
        (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);

customElements.define("my-button", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.setAttribute("hidden", true);
    setTimeout(() => { // wait for lightDOM to be parsed
      let type = this.getAttribute("type");
      let [el, attr] = (type == "link") ? ["a", "href"] : ["button", "type"];
      let button = createElement(el, {
            [attr]: this.getAttribute(attr),
            onclick: (evt) => alert(`Web Component ${type||"button"} clicked`)
      });
      // .children will not include textNodes, all Nodes are *moved*
      button.append(...this.childNodes);
      // lightDOM is empty now
      this.append(button);
      this.removeAttribute("hidden");
    });
  }
});
<style>
  [type="link"] {
    display: inline-block;
    background: pink;
    padding: 1em;
  }
</style>

<my-button>
  I am the button Label
  <div style="font-size:60px"></div>
</my-button>

<my-button type="link">
  Another label
  <div style="font-size:40px"></div>
</my-button>




You do not need that setTimeout when you stuff all data in attributes instead of lightDOM.
The connectedCallback fires on the opening tag... so can access all attributes

ShadowDOM and <slot> might give a better UI experience, but requires more code.

CSS :not(:defined) can help, but you are now relying on dependencies outside the Web Component

you could also do this.replaceWith(button) at the end, if your Web Component was only about creating that link/button
Makes for some cleaner HTML

If you really want to execute after the constructor and before the connectedCallback you can ABUSE the attributeChangedCallback because that will fire for every declared ObservedAttribute before the connectedCallback fires on the <my-button> opening tag.
BUT! The lightDOM inside your <my-button> still was not parsed yet.

There are "gurus" out there that tell you to "solve" this with defer, async, import or type="module"
They have no clue what is actually happening... all they do is delay execution of the whole JavaScript file

The other answer doesn't work always. You can't access attributes in the constructor when the DOM wasn't parsed.
Here is an MVP showing the fault in the other answer: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/970xbetz/




Thanks for the brief deep dive provided with your answer and the linked article. I as much appreciated the calm style of your comments regarding my proposed beforeconnected approach/implementation(s). I gained a lot from all of it.

What the OP is looking for ... quoting the OP ...

It would've been nice if there was a beforeConnectedCallback

From my above comment ...

@OscarR ... I'm with Bergi the attribute changed lifecycle callback in combination with the connectedCallback gives one everything one does need to know. Since your component features a sole type attribute you can build upon this approach.



function handleBeforeConnected(/* argument/s, */evt) {
  const { type, target } = evt;

  console.log(
    'handleBeforeConnected ...', { type, target, attrNames: target.getAttributeNames() }
  );
}

class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  static observedAttributes = ['type', 'trait'];

  #expectedInitialChangeCount;
  #initialAttrChangeCount = 0;
  #isInitialized = false;

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addEventListener(
      'beforeconnected', handleBeforeConnected/*.bind( <null|this>, <args array> )*/
    );
    const observedSet = new Set(MyComponent.observedAttributes);
    const attrNameSet = new Set(this.getAttributeNames());

    // console.log([...attrNameSet.intersection(observedSet)]);

    this.#expectedInitialChangeCount = [...attrNameSet.intersection(observedSet)].length;
    this.#isInitialized = this.#initialAttrChangeCount >= this.#expectedInitialChangeCount;

    if (this.#isInitialized) {
      this.dispatchEvent(
        new /*Custom*/Event('beforeconnected'/*, { detail: {} } */)
      );
    }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('connectedCallback ...', { target: this });
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(/*attrName, recentValue, currentValue*/) {
    if (!this.#isInitialized) {
      if (++this.#initialAttrChangeCount >= this.#expectedInitialChangeCount) {

        this.#isInitialized = true;

        this.dispatchEvent(
          new /*Custom*/Event('beforeconnected'/*, { detail: {} } */)
        );
      }
    }/* else { ... } */
  }
}
customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 32%;
}
my-component {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 8px 4px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  width: 67%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
<my-component type="button" trait="triggers" foo="bar">triggering button</my-component>
<my-component type="link" bar="baz">basic link</my-component>
<my-component biz="buzz">unspecified component</my-component>



Within a next iteration step one could provide an abstraction layer (e.g. an own ConnectedTarget class) which not only encapsulates all the code related to a proper beforeconnected handling, but which likewise incorporates the connected handling.
The implementation of the OP's MyComponent class, then extending ConnectedTarget, will be much more lightweight as shown with the following example ...


function handleBeforeConnected(/* argument/s, */evt) {
  const { type, target } = evt;

  console.log(
    'handleBeforeConnected ...', { type, target, attrNames: target.getAttributeNames() }
  );
}
function handleConnected(/* argument/s, */evt) {
  const { type, target } = evt;

  console.log('handleConnected ...', { type, target });
}

class MyComponent extends ConnectedTarget {
  static observedAttributes = ['type', 'trait'];

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addEventListener(
      'beforeconnected', handleBeforeConnected/*.bind( <null|this>, <args array> )*/
    );
    this.addEventListener(
      'connected', handleConnected/*.bind( <null|this>, <args array> )*/
    );
  }
}
customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 32%;
}
my-component {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 8px 4px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  width: 67%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
<my-component type="button" trait="triggers" foo="bar">triggering button</my-component>
<my-component type="link" bar="baz">basic link</my-component>
<my-component biz="buzz">unspecified component</my-component>

<script>
class ConnectedTarget extends HTMLElement {

  #expectedCount;
  #initialCount = 0;
  #isInitialized = false;

  constructor() {
    super();

    const observedSet = new Set(new.target.observedAttributes ?? []);
    const attrNameSet = new Set(this.getAttributeNames());

    // console.log([...attrNameSet.intersection(observedSet)]);

    this.#expectedCount = [...attrNameSet.intersection(observedSet)].length;
    this.#isInitialized = this.#initialCount >= this.#expectedCount;

    if (this.#isInitialized) {
      this.dispatchEvent(
        new /*Custom*/Event('beforeconnected'/*, { detail: {} } */)
      );
    }
  }

  attributeChangedCallback() {
    if (!this.#isInitialized) {
      if (++this.#initialCount >= this.#expectedCount) {

        this.#isInitialized = true;

        this.dispatchEvent(
          new /*Custom*/Event('beforeconnected'/*, { detail: {} } */)
        );
      }
    }
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new /*Custom*/Event('connected'/*, { detail: {} } */)
    );
  }
}
</script>



The upcoming second last iteration takes into account every beneath comment of Danny '365CSI' Engelman, regarding script loading, as well as FOUCs and Layout shifts.
The latter is what the OP does want to avoid.
Thus the this implementation now is agnostic of script loading order and independent of any particular timing of any valid customElements.define execution.
All current changes had to be applied exclusively to the ConnectedTarget class, the MyComponent class remained unchanged.


body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 32%;
}
my-component {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 8px 4px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  width: 67%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
<script>
class ConnectedTarget extends HTMLElement {

  #expectedCount = null;
  #initialCount = 0;
  #isInitialized = false;

  attributeChangedCallback() {
    if (this.#expectedCount === null) {

      const observedSet = new Set(this.constructor.observedAttributes ?? []);
      const attrNameSet = new Set(this.getAttributeNames());

      // console.log([...attrNameSet.intersection(observedSet)]);

      this.#expectedCount = [...attrNameSet.intersection(observedSet)].length;
      this.#isInitialized = this.#initialCount >= this.#expectedCount;
    }
    if (!this.#isInitialized) {
      if (++this.#initialCount >= this.#expectedCount) {

        this.#isInitialized = true;

        this.dispatchEvent(
          new /*Custom*/Event('beforeconnected'/*, { detail: {} } */)
        );
      }
    }
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    if (!this.#isInitialized && this.#expectedCount === null) {

      this.dispatchEvent(
        new /*Custom*/Event('beforeconnected'/*, { detail: {} } */)
      );
    }
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new /*Custom*/Event('connected'/*, { detail: {} } */)
    );
  }
}
</script>

<script>
function handleBeforeConnected(/* argument/s, */evt) {
  const { type, target } = evt;

  console.log(
    'handleBeforeConnected ...', { type, target, attrNames: target.getAttributeNames() }
  );
}
function handleConnected(/* argument/s, */evt) {
  const { type, target } = evt;

  console.log('handleConnected ...', { type, target });
}

class MyComponent extends ConnectedTarget {
  static observedAttributes = ['type', 'trait'];

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addEventListener(
      'beforeconnected', handleBeforeConnected/*.bind( <null|this>, <args array> )*/
    );
    this.addEventListener(
      'connected', handleConnected/*.bind( <null|this>, <args array> )*/
    );
  }
}
</script>

<script>
customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
</script>


<my-component type="button" trait="triggers" foo="bar">triggering button</my-component>
<my-component type="link" bar="baz">basic link</my-component>
<my-component biz="buzz">unspecified component</my-component>



There is yet the final iteration which got its refinement by adopting Danny '365CSI' Engelman's, my-botton-component scenario.

The beforeconnected event now gets dispatched as soon as it can be determined that the processing of the component's root has started, which is ...

any first occurring initial attribute change, for components that feature observed attributes.
a shammed beforeconnected event at the connected lifecycle callback.


Nevertheless the OP at this very early state can preserve the component from being initially rendered by hiding it, as already proposed by Danny '365CSI' Engelman.


Likewise an additional initializedroot event gets dispatched as soon as ...

either the last available attribute from the static observed attributes array has initially changed,

or the shamming from the connected lifecycle callback took care of it.



Note ... initializedroot therefore can bee seen as, and also should be used as, a specialized version (especially with available and to be initialized observed attributes) of the connected lifecycle callback.



The code example gets provided in a way which most likely would cause  Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC).
The code base of the ConnectedTarget class had to be refactored on a larger scale, whereas the new MyButton class which extends ConnectedTarget features a much smaller footprint.


body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 32%;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  width: 67%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
<script>
class ConnectedTarget extends HTMLElement {

  #expectedInitialAttrCount = null;
  #currentInitialAttrCount = 0;
  #isRootInitialized = false;
  #isConnected = false;

  attributeChangedCallback(name, recent, current) {
    if (this.#expectedInitialAttrCount === null) {

      // - the earliest point at which one can be informed
      //   about the processing of the component's root.

      this.dispatchEvent(
        new Event('beforeconnected'),
      );
      const observedSet = new Set(this.constructor.observedAttributes ?? []);
      const attrNameSet = new Set(this.getAttributeNames());

      // console.log([...attrNameSet.intersection(observedSet)]);

      this.#expectedInitialAttrCount =
        [...attrNameSet.intersection(observedSet)].length;

      this.#isRootInitialized =
        this.#currentInitialAttrCount >= this.#expectedInitialAttrCount;
    }

    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('attributechanged', {
        detail: {
          name,
          value: {
            recent,
            current,
          },
          isConnected: this.#isConnected,
          isInitialized: this.#isRootInitialized,
        },
      }),
    );

    if (!this.#isRootInitialized) {
      if (++this.#currentInitialAttrCount >= this.#expectedInitialAttrCount) {

        this.#isRootInitialized = true;

        this.dispatchEvent(
          new Event('initializedroot'),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    if (this.#expectedInitialAttrCount === null) {

      // - with no observed attributes one has to sham both
      //   events, `beforeconnected` and `initializedroot`.

      this.#expectedInitialAttrCount = 0;

      this.dispatchEvent(
        new Event('beforeconnected'),
      );
      if (!this.#isRootInitialized) {

        this.#isRootInitialized = true;

        this.dispatchEvent(
          new Event('initializedroot'),
        );
      }
    }
    this.#isConnected = true;

    this.dispatchEvent(
      new Event('connected'),
    );
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    this.#isConnected = false;

    this.dispatchEvent(
      new Event('disconnected'),
    );
  }

  adoptedCallback() {
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new Event('adopted'),
    );
  }
}
</script>

<script>
const createElement =
  (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);

function hideComponent(target) {
  target.setAttribute('hidden', true);

  console.log('hideComponent ...', { target })
}
function renderComponent(target) {

  // wait for lightDOM to be parsed
  setTimeout(() => {

    const type = target.getAttribute('type');
    const [elm, attr] = (type === 'link') ? ['a', 'href'] : ['button', 'type'];

    const button = createElement(elm, {
      onclick: evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log(`Web Component ${ type || 'button' } clicked.`);
      },
      [attr]: target.getAttribute(attr),
    });

    // children will not include textNodes, all Nodes are *moved*.
    button.append(...target.childNodes);

    // lightDOM is empty now.
    target.append(button);
    target.removeAttribute('hidden');

    console.log('renderComponent ...', { target });
  });
}


function handleAttributeChanged(evt) {
  const { target, type, detail } = evt;

  console.log(
    'handleAttributeChanged ...', {
      target, type, detail, attrNames: target.getAttributeNames()
    },
  );
}

function handleBeforeConnected(evt) {
  const { target, type } = evt;

  console.log(
    'handleBeforeConnected ...', { target, type, attrNames: target.getAttributeNames() },
  );
  hideComponent(target);
}
function handleInitializedRoot(evt) {
  const { target, type } = evt;

  console.log(
    '... handleInitializedRoot ...\n... invoke renderComponent ...', {
      target, type, attrNames: target.getAttributeNames(),
    },
  );
  renderComponent(target);
}

function handleConnected(evt) {
  const { target, type } = evt;

  console.log('handleConnected ...', { target, type });
  console.log('\n');
}


class MyButton extends ConnectedTarget {

  static observedAttributes = ['type', 'href'];

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addEventListener('attributechanged', handleAttributeChanged);

    this.addEventListener('beforeconnected', handleBeforeConnected);
    this.addEventListener('initializedroot', handleInitializedRoot);

    this.addEventListener('connected', handleConnected);

    // this.addEventListener('disconnected', handleDisconnected); 
    // this.addEventListener('adopted', handleAdopted);
  }
}
</script>

<script>
customElements.define('my-button', MyButton);
</script>


<style>
  my-button {
    a,
    button {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 2px;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    &[type="link"] a {
      background: pink;
    }
    div {
      font-size: 60px;
      /* font-size: 60px!important; */
    }
  }
</style>


<my-button>
  I am the button Label
  <div style="font-size: 1.2em;">;-)</div>
</my-button>

<my-button type="button">
  I am the button Label
  <div style="font-size: 1.4em;"></div>
</my-button>

<my-button type="link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
  Link type label
  <div style="font-size: 1.4em;"></div>
</my-button>




SO snippets, like CodePen and JSFidlle and the lot are all deceptive. They execute the JavaScript after HTML is parsed, When the Web Component is defined before DOM is parsed this.getAttributeNames() in that constructor will return an empty array. Wrap your code in a <script> element at the start of the SO Snippet...

Here is an MVP where your constructor accessing attributes fails: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/970xbetz/

That's the same effect as setting <script async src="..."> or <script type="module" src="...">; all .define() code will execute after DOM is parsed.. causing the FOUCs and Layout Shifts OP wants to avoid (if possible)

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman ... you're right. Within a third iteration I provided changes exclusively to the ConnectedTarget implementation which now is agnostic to script loading and render order as well as it is to the execution time of customElements.define.

From .bind I can tell you're an oldskool JavaScript geezer like me. I spent many hours on this in the past resulting in the Dev.to blog. I hadn't experimented with events.. because those are synchronous, and the whole trick is to wait till the event loop is empty (when making sure ALL lightDOM exists). I cleaned your code, added more logs, it still doesn't work with Events: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/ogtL730b/ its not about what is displayed but the full F12 console. In my browser the last 2 handleBeforeConnected execute after the connectedCallback

I am no Event guru, all I know is that they are synchronous, so I presume while your code is busy in the Event loop the DOM continues parsing, and thus the connectedCallback fires on the opening tag

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman ... firefox, chrome, safari (all on mac obviously), all log the same ... for each component with resolved id ... 'handleBeforeConnected ...' always before 'handleConnected ...' ... and for all alike, for the ones with real observed attributes as much as for the ones without observed attributes.

I see my fault now, my last 2 components did not have a observed attribute on them... hmm, I have to sleep on this, this implementation now relies on attributes the user might not add (like I did)
